# Matlab rotate and translate images in 2D

Tags: image, matlab, rotation, overlay, translate-animation

I would like to overlay two images (forearm.jpg and wrist.jpg) over a 2-DOF planar (2D) arm (code below). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
length = 200;
L1 = 11; %set length of forarm, L1, and wrist, L2
L2 = 8;
figure;
data = transpose([linspace(0,1,length); linspace(0,1,length); 1:length]); %dummy data
time = 0; %initialize time

i = 1; %initialize counter
h = animatedline;
while(time<=length-1)
    theta1 = (pi/180) * (170*data(i,1)); %map data to rotational space
    theta2 = (pi/180) * (135*data(i,2) - 45);
    time = data(i,3);
    i = i + 1; %count
    clearpoints(h)
    h = animatedline([0, L1 * cos(theta1), L1 * cos(theta1) + ...
        L2 * cos(theta1 + theta2)], [0, L1 * sin(theta1), ...
        L1 * sin(theta1) + L2 * sin(theta1 + theta2)]);
    axis([-20 20 -10 20]);
    drawnow     
    pause(0.001)
end
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @rayryeng How to I replace the 2-link arm (in the code) with two images (each image in place of a link of the arm)?